# Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client

Tags: php, apache, timeout, request-timed-out

I do a small for loop in `PHP` on my `localhost` machine, it contains `sleep(60)` to echo some text every 60 seconds .. but before the first loop finishes, I got an error in the browser that says:

`Request Time-out`

`Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.`

I've tried a combination of :

`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);`

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 90000);`

`set_time_limit(0);`

and I've also tried to set these variables in `php.ini` but to no avail, the browser keeps displaying this message as from the first loop.

I want to know, is this a browser specific time-out ? if yes, where can change this value in Safari/Chrome/IE & FF.

thanks so much in advance.

EDIT: the behavior on FF is different, it keeps loading forever, unlike Safari which displays this message.

Comment: Simple workaround: send a blank character every 10 seconds, this keeps the connection open and is not shown in a client side html view.

Comment: what do you mean by send ? just echo ?

Comment: Sure, `echo ' ';obflush();flush();`